# C# Com Interop Method is not a member of error

Tags: c#, c++, com

I have a C# dll I've exposed to COM and I'm getting the following error when I try to compile the c++ application:

```
error C2039: 'ValidateCredentials_2' : is not a member of '_com_ptr_t<class _com_IIID<struct ExactaLogin::IAuthorizerInterop,&struct __s_GUID _GUID_00020400_0000_0000_c000_000000000046> >'
```

When I compile the c++ dll I see the following in the tlh file generated by the #import i'm doing:

```
//
// Forward references and typedefs
//

struct __declspec(uuid("4b547e3d-3d30-4981-9999-f72f52a4fc01"))
/* dispinterface */ IAuthorizerInterop;
struct /* coclass */ AuthorizerInterop;

//
// Smart pointer typedef declarations
//

_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IAuthorizerInterop, __uuidof(IDispatch));

//
// Type library items
//
struct __declspec(uuid("4b547e3d-3d30-4981-9999-f72f52a4fc01"))
IAuthorizerInterop : IDispatch
{
    //
    // Wrapper methods for error-handling
    //

    // Methods:
    VARIANT_BOOL ValidateCredentials (
        _bstr_t applicationName,
        _bstr_t domainName,
        _bstr_t domainUserNameToAuthenticate,
        _bstr_t domainPasswordToAuthenticate );
    VARIANT_BOOL ValidateCredentials_2 (
        _bstr_t applicationName,
        _bstr_t domainUserNameToAuthenticate,
        _bstr_t domainPasswordToAuthenticate );
};
```

I have defined my object in c++ with the following:

```
#import "ExactaLogin.tlb"
using namespace ExactaLogin;

IAuthorizerInteropPtr m_spDomainLoginAuthorizer;
```

My c# classes are defined as follows:

```
[Guid("45329257-BFF4-4CF7-9A83-22D87A1FB757")]
[ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[ProgId("ExactaLogin.AuthorizerInterop")]
[ComVisible(true)]
public class AuthorizerInterop : IAuthorizerInterop

[Guid("4B547E3D-3D30-4981-9999-F72F52A4FC01")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
[ComVisible(true)]
public interface IAuthorizerInterop
```

Not quite sure what's going on.  If I change the code to use `ValidateCredentials` instead of `ValidateCredentials_2` it results in the same error.

### EDIT

I'm calling the method in the c++ app as follows

```
m_spDomainLoginAuthorizer.ValidateCredentials_2(_bstr_t(m_szAppName), _bstr_t(m_szUserName), _bstr_t(m_szPassword));
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a really stupid mistake above.

The call should obviously be accessed like a pointer.  So the fix is:

```
m_spDomainLoginAuthorizer->ValidateCredentials_2(_bstr_t(m_szAppName), _bstr_t(m_szUserName), _bstr_t(m_szPassword));
```

and not

```
m_spDomainLoginAuthorizer.ValidateCredentials_2(_bstr_t(m_szAppName), _bstr_t(m_szUserName), _bstr_t(m_szPassword));
```

`->` instead of `.`